# Run python package in cmd with own name

Tags: python, pip, command-line-interface

I try to learn and publish python packageing. I can run my package with `python module.module` but I want to my package can run in cmd/bash directly with own name. For example

```
youtube-dl <arguments>
```

or

```
httpie <arguments>
```

How can I do my package like this?

Comment: If you only want to run it locally, you may use `alias youtube-dl="python youtube-dl"`

Comment: Maybe [this Python official doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) doc can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+command+line

Answer (score 1):

Like [this Python official doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) about packaging to PYPI explains, you can use the build package for this.

For this you do need some setup. The documentation will give you a basic project structure setup. Then add the following line to your `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` file. I formatted it for the setup.py version of the file as i prefer that option.

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['YOUR_CLI_NAME=YOUR_SRC_FILE:YOUR_MAIN_FUNCTION']
},
```

The above code will configure your program to work when running `YOUR_CLI_NAME` in the command line.

You only need to package the program for PIP and install it.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade build

python -m build
```

This will create a `dist` directory and build your install files. You can install it using

```
pip install your_wheel_file.whl
```

Optionally you can also upload to the PYPI archive.

I hope this helps you, please refer to the documentation i linked above for any further information. It's all in there!